# What is the Javascript equivalent of writing 'If not"

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Python programmer here.

I don't know how to write this. I tried using 'if !in' and '!if in', but I don't know how. Tried to Google it but got no results.

Comment: Based on your previous questions, you already know that parentheses are required. Are you actually trying to write a "if not in (array)" condition?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is

```
if(!condition){
    expression();
}
```

Note that you need parenthesis around the condition.

---

@plalx wants a [formal definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-if-statement), and here you go:

```
IfStatement:
    if(Expression) Statement else Statement
    if(Expression) Statement
```

In case of any ambiguity the `else` would be matched with the nearest `if`.

Comment: Why not expressing your comment in the code rather than making it a comment? `if (!(condition)) { ... }` Commenting rather than making code explicit is a very bad habit most programmers have... ;)

Comment: @plalx I believe this is the cleanest way to demonstrate the syntax.

Comment: How could it be the cleanest if you need an additional comment? This sounds like, to perform some process you need to: `doThis() //by the way you also need to doThat() before calling doThis()`. It's much cleaner to just `doThat(); doThis();`

Answer (score 1):

If you have some value:

```
var excludeMe = "something unwanted";
```

Then you can use the following if statement:

```
if(myTestCase !== excludeMe) { //do something...}
```

Keep in mind that != does not check type and !== does check type. So, 1 != "1" is false and 1 !== "1" is true.